# Rails 4, JS ERB response renders application.html instead of specified partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a very simple ajax call to a controller action, which is supposed to render a form to a specified div. Except nothing renders to the div while everything in the controller, server and console suggests it should work. I've checked and double checked the divs are named the same, I've renamed things to see if there is a clash, I even have something on the same page that does what I want this to do - but it just wont work.

On further inspection in Chrome it appears the the 'js.erb' isn't being evaluated properly. 
When the file is rendered it should output the contents of my js erb file (which in other instances works), except its outputting the entire layout with the partial encased.

I have put an alert in here also for good measure, which isnt firing (it fires in the project asive tested with other js controllers).

```
 .........
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <section class='col-lg-12'>
      <div class='panel panel-default'>
        <div class='panel-body'>
          alert('test');
          $("#membershipForm").html("<form novalidate=\"novalidate\"
```

Here is the controller action

```
  def new
    @membership = Membership.new(membershipable_type: params[:membershipable_type],
                                 membershipable_id: params[:membershipable_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'new' }
    end
  end
```

and here the new.js.erb

```
alert('test');
$("#membershipForm").html("<%= j render('memberships/partials/form') %>");
```

This is very strange, I really don't understand what's going on.

Comment: did you include remote: true?

Comment: Can you add your log output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `layout: false` in `render` method. Like this `render(template: 'foo/bar', layout: false)`

Also i think implementation via `.js.erb` not nice way for other developers. I recommend you to implement like I described below.

Remove your `new.js.erb` and add this to `new.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  alert('test');
  $("#membershipForm").html(<%= render_to_string(template: 'members/partials/form', layout: false) %>);
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is undoubtedly to do with your `format.js { render "new" }` - you'll be better with the following:

```
#app/controllers/memberships_controller.rb
class MembershipsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :html

   def new
       @membership = Membership.new membershipable_type: params[:membershipable_type], membershipable_id: params[:membershipable_id]
   end

   def create
       @membership = Membership.new membership_params
       @membership.save
   end

   private

   def membership_params
       params.require(:membership).permit(:membershipable_type, :membershipable_id)
   end
end
```

The above will invoke the `.js.erb` files for the respective actions:

```
#app/views/memberships/new.js.erb
$("#membershipForm").html("<%= j render 'memberships/partials/form' %>");
```

This should work.

Comment: Rich, I have a similar problem, but since there are more actions to do I don't know how to pull it off. Could you pls take a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817690/rails-ajax-js-erb-same-route-more-actions